# ¿ Es necesario un middlewarecuando tengo un mqtt broker?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mqtt

Hola a todos estoy creando un proyecto con sensores de humedad y temperatura conectados a un ESP8266, actualmente tengo funcionando un mqtt broker (mosquitto) y además tengo un middleware con nodeJs junto a la base de datos en mongoDB hice un crud de prueba, me saltó la duda si es que es estrictamente necesario tener la comunicación del middleware junto al mqtt para poder consumirlos desde un front en react o solo me basta tener el broker ?

Comment: Si los datos antiguos no te interesan, digamos que solo quieres mostrar cosas en tiempo real, puedes sacar node y la base datos. Es decir lo que tu llamas "Middleware" solo lo necesitas para obtener información histórica

Comment: Entiendo, si mi idea es desde el front es consumir estos datos y crear una especie de dashboard por lo que como dices serían datos históricos, gracias por tu respuesta !